# PHP не может убить процесс

Tags: php, linux

У меня на сервере Ubuntu 16.04 запущен процесс с ID, грубо говоря 21505.

При запуске php скрипта

```
    system('kill 21505');
```

Никаких ошибок не выводит, но процесс продолжает существовать.
Что мне нужно сделать, чтобы команда работала?

Comment: Как минимум убедиться, что достаточно прав у этого процесса для завершения другого.

Comment: как дать ему эти права?

Comment: Самый простой вариант - запускать скрипт из-под рута.

Comment: Надеюсь скрипт у вас не доступен из Web? А то можете словить много попоболи дав ему root права и разрешив исполнение system